# Vuejs: empty styles for child component

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

```
<template>
  <li class="movie-item">
  </li>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
  .movie-item {
    width: 320px;
  }
<style>
```

I added these styles in child component, but in the browser these styles are not applied. Just empty style tag:

[image]

Comment: close your `<style>` tag. `</style>`. Whatever tool you're using should have warned you while compiling.

Comment: lol, you're right. thank you